# Incrementing variable inside object

Tags: javascript, function, object, increment

I'm trying to increment a value of a variable inside object with a function.

This works

```
var player = {
  tech: 0,
  energy: 0
};

function getResource2(amount, id) {
  player.tech += amount;
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = player.tech;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  getResource2(5, "Tech");
}, 1000);
```

And this doesn't

```
var player = {
  tech: 0,
  energy: 0
};

function getResource(resource, amount, id) {
  resource += amount;
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = resource;

window.setInterval(function() {
  getResource(player.tech, 1, "Tech");
}, 1000);
```

I don't want to repeat my code too much. I want to use function parameter to target variable inside object rather than hardcoding it myself.

Comment: Pass `player` instead, then increment `player.tech`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by passing the player to the function, in addition to the resource. Then you should be able to increment the target resource like this:

`player[resource] += amount;`

The whole function would look something like this:

```
function getResource(player, resource, amount, id) {
    player[resource] += amount;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = player[resource];
}
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log("I'm working");
    getResource(player, 'tech' , 1, "Tech");
    console.log(player.tech);
}, 1000);
```

Note that `tech` is being passed as a string literal.

Comment: I'm getting NaN as a result. Could you check my fiddle and tell me where is the problem ? [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xvty1c8c/)

Answer (score 0):

Sculper already provided good answer, but I prefer keeping logic inside object in more object oriented way.

Example:

```
  var player = {
  tech: 0,
  energy: 0,

  getResource: function(amount, callback){
      this.tech += amount;

      if(callback)
          callback(this);
  }
};

var techResourceCallback = function(playerObject){
    var techElementId = 'Tech';
    document.getElementById(techElementId).innerHTML = playerObject.tech;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  player.getResource(1, techResourceCallback);
}, 1000);
```